# how to efficiently access 3^20 vectors in a 2^30 bits of memory

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, multidimensional-array

I want to store a 20-dimensional array where each coordinate can have 3 values, 
in a minimal amount of memory (2^30 or 1 Gigabyte).
It is not a sparse array, I really need every value.
Furthermore I want the values to be integers of arbirary but fixed precision, 
say 256 bits or 8 words

example;

```
set_big_array(1,0,0,0,1,2,2,0,0,2,1,1,2,0,0,0,1,1,1,2, some_256_bit_value);
```

and

```
get_big_array(1,0,0,0,1,2,2,0,0,2,1,1,2,0,0,0,1,1,1,2, &some_256_bit_value);
```

Because the value 3 is relative prime of 2. its difficult to implement this using 
efficient bitwise shift, and and or operators.
I want this to be as fast as possible.

any thoughts?

Comment: Err... you can't: 3^20 / 2^30 = 3.2473210254684091. Not enough bits...

Comment: Do you want 3^20 vectors or 3^20 256-bit values?

Comment: More to the point (8 * 2^30) / 3^20 is about 2.5, so you have 2.5 bits per array entry. It's going to take 99% compression to store 256-bit values into 2.5 bits per value. It potentially could be done for example if vast regions of the 20-D space all take the same value, so that e.g. a run-length-encoding works astonishingly well. Or if only 4 values actually occur then a simple substitution compression does it. Try writing a large sample of the data to disk and compressing it with your favourite file compression program. If it can't get 99% then likely neither can you...

Comment: You're wanting to store almost 104Gigabytes memory in 1Gigabyte of memory?  Either you need a awesome compression algorithm, or a large harddrive.  I think indexing the array is the least of your problems.

Comment: @MerickOWA: to be fair, the indexing compounds the existing problem :-)  Supposing that the data does compress, the performance characteristics that the questioner is talking about require not just any old compression algorithm, but one with random-access decompression. Even less likely.

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us a bit more about what you are trying to do. How did you come up with the need for such an array?

Answer (score 3):

Seems tricky to me without some compression:

```
3^20 = 3486784401 values to store
256bits / 8bitsPerByte = 32 bytes per value
3486784401 * 32 = 111577100832 size for values in bytes
111577100832 / (1024^3) = 104 Gb
```

You're trying to fit 104 Gb in 1 Gb. There'd need to be some pattern to the data that could be used to compress it.

Sorry, I know this isn't much help, but maybe you can rethink your strategy.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3.48e9 variants of 20-tuple of indexes that are 0,1,2.  If you wish to store a 256 bit value at each index, that means you're talking about 8.92e11 bits - about a terabit, or about 100GB.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but that sounds computationally expensive.  It may be reasonable feasible as a memory-mapped file, and may be reasonably fast as a memory-mapped file on an SSD.

What are you trying to do?

So, a practical solution would be to use a 64-bit OS and a large memory-mapped file (preferably on an SSD) and simply compute the address for a given element in the typical way for arrays, i.e. as `sum-of(forall-i(i-th-index * 3^i)) * 32 bytes` in pseudeo-math.  Or, use a very very expensive machine with that much memory, or another algorithm that doesn't require this array in the first place.

A few notes on platforms: Windows 7 supports just 192GB of memory, so using physical memory for a structure like this is possible but really pushing it (more expensive editions support more).  If you can find a machine at all that is.  According to [microsoft's page on the matter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx) the user-mode virtual address space is 7-8TB, so mmap/virtual memory should be doable.  Alex Ionescu explains [why there's such a low limit on virtual memory despite an apparently 64-bit architecture](http://www.alex-ionescu.com/?p=50).  Wikipedia puts [linux's addressable limits at 128TB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Linux), though probably that's before the kernel/usermode split.

Assuming you want to address such a multidimensional array, you must process each index at least once: that means any algorithm will be O(N) where N is the number of indexes.  As mentioned before, you don't need to convert to base-2 addressing or anything else, the only thing that matters is that you can compute the *integer* offset - and which base the maths happens in is irrelevant.  You should use the most compact representation possible and ignore the fact that each dimension is not a multiple of 2.

So, for a 16-dimensional array, that address computation function could be:

```
int offset = 0;
for(int ii=0;ii<16;ii++)
    offset = offset*3 + indexes[ii];
return &the_array[offset];
```

As previously said, this is just the common array indexing formula, nothing special about it. Note that even for "just" 16 dimensions, if each item is 32 bytes, you're dealing with a little more than a gigabyte of data.

Comment: well 20 is a bit steep. 16 would do for now. The point was more how to efficiently map a 'base 3' word onto a 'base 2' address, in order to have a O(1) fast lookup of my array value

Comment: You don't need to map a 'base 3' word onto a 'base 2' address - you need to map it onto a plain integer offset.  That's just the same as any other multi-dimensional array needs to - I've included an example, but other addressing schemes exist too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i understand your question wrong. But can't you just use a normal array?

```
INT256 bigArray[3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3];
OR
INT256 ********************bigArray = malloc(3^20 * 8);

bigArray[1][0][0][1][2][0][1][1][0][0][0][0][1][1][2][1][1][1][1][1] = some_256_bit_value;
```

etc.

Edit:
Will not work because you would need 3^20 * 8Byte = ca. 25GByte.
The malloc variant is wrong.

Comment: Your last assignment will work only with the first declaration.

Comment: If you have a computer/OS which can allocate this on the stack or heap I'm impressed ;)

Comment: Let's wait 10 Years then we will have no problem with 111 GByte of heap ;)

Comment: Actually, I think it's doable as a mmapped file - I've done matrix math on things like that, but it's *slooowww* - 'course, nowadays we've got SSD's - it might be good enough, it really depends on what you're trying to do, and on access patterns, of course.

Comment: It will also wear out your ssd pretty quickly.

Comment: that's the "depending on access patterns bit" ;-) - it's still probably cheaper to replace the SSD every few months than an actual machine with that much memory - using an SLC SSD would help too.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by doing a direct calculation of the address, then see if I can optimize it

address = 0;
for(i=15; i>=0; i--)
{
  address = 3*address + array[i];
}

address = address * number_of_bytes_needed_for_array_value

Answer (score 0):

2^30 bits is 2^27 bytes so not actually a gigabyte, it's an eighth of a gigabyte.

It appears impossible to do because of the mathematics although of course you can create the data size bigger then compress it, which may get you down to the required size although it cannot guarantee. (It must fail to some of the time as the compression is lossless).

If you do not require immediate "random" access your solution may be a "variable sized" two-bit word so your most commonly stored value takes only 1 bit and the other two take 2 bits.

If 0 is your most common value then:
0 = 0
10 = 1
11 = 2

or something like that.

In that case you will be able to store your bits in sequence this way.

It could take up to 2^40 bits this way but probably will not.
You could pre-run through your data and see which is the commonly occurring value and use that to indicate your single-bit word.
You can also compress your data after you have serialized it in up to 2^40 bits.

My assumption here is that you will be using disk possibly with memory mapping as you are unlikely to have that much memory available.

My assumption is that space is everything and not time.

Comment: Well 20 is a bit steep. 16 would do for now. The point of my question was how to efficiently map a 'base 3' word onto a 'base 2' address, The reason is I want a very fast lookup of my array value. I tried a hash before (using uthash.h) but that is not fast enough. I am now considering a direct translation to memory.

Comment: I will simply start by doing a direct calculation of the address and ake it form there

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at something like [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/), an implementation of the STL designed for handling very large volumes of data

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use a pointer-to-array<sup>20</sup> to have your compiler implement the index calculations for you:

```
/* Note: there are 19 of the [3]'s below */
my_256bit_type (*foo)[3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3];

foo = allocate_giant_array();

foo[0][1][1][0][2][1][2][2][0][2][1][0][2][1][0][0][2][1][0][0] = some_256bit_value;
```